# I want to extract enddate from date (when the new date was updated new dates day -1 is the ennddate) but the most recent date is same for that enddate

Tags: sql-server

```sql
SELECT [DATE] as startdate,
       dateadd(d,-1,[DATE]) as enddate,
       [LINE],
       [STATION] 
FROM [ALPHA].[dbo].[new_test] 
order by 1 desc
```

I need to get the most recent date is same as most recent enddate

Comment: Your description is not clear, so I suggest you add a few sample rows from your table along with the desired values for enddate. I do not understand how **subtracting** a day from startdate produces a useful or correct value for enddate. You also refer to "most recent date"; that reference needs more clarity and detail.

Comment: Some sample data would help here